# Having trouble returning a bool value for a function in php

Tags: php, boolean

I am trying to use an if statement to use a bool value and it does not work. The top are my functions I am using and the bottom is the if statment.  When I change the if statment to a false I get the result, but I need both the true and false bools. Any tips

```
      public function find($key)   {  
    $this->find_helper($key, $this->root);      
}

public function find_helper($key, $current){
    while ($current){
        if($current->data == $key){
            echo " current";
            return true;
        }
        else if ($key < $current->data){
            $current= $current->leftChild;
            //echo " left ";
            }
        else {
            $current=$current->rightChild;
            //echo " right ";
            }
    }
    return false;
}


      if($BST->find($randomNumber)){//how do I get this to return a true value?
        echo  " same ";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You return from `find_helper()` but not from `find()`. Without the `return` (seen below), the `find_helper()` method is called, but whatever that method returns is *discarded*. So your `find()` method ends up returning *neither* value (which PHP translates to null anyway).

```
public function find($key) {  
    return $this->find_helper($key, $this->root);      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator

```
 public function find($key)   {  
     return ($this->find_helper($key, $this->root)) ? true : false;      
  }
```

Comment: The problem is with the missing `return`, not the ternary operator. Besides, the helper method already returns true/false; why do you need to repeat it?

Comment: that's superfluous if you use the return value in a simple if statement later. Additionally you should consider (bool) which is easier to read.

Comment: @hakre: That's not necessary either. Just do a direct return. No casting, no ternary, no whatever else. Just the method call, and return.

Comment: you short-read me: What I wrote: **It's superfluous.** - so you did not add any news with your comment nor insight for me. the cast is just a hint to the one who suggested to use the ternary operator. It can (but must not) make sense if you want to explicitly return a bool from some function.

Comment: +1 for @BoltClock solution, my bad i didn't see the code properly. using just return is reccomended.